# How to fix: 'TypeError: entities is not iterable' in ngRx/entity

Tags: ngrx-store, ngrx-entity

How to fix: 'TypeError: entities not iterable' in ngRx? I am new in using ngrx functionality just referring this URL - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=igc5rBN50wk&list=PLaMbwDs23r4KXoMucJEyUAvamQ-kFNBvC&index=7

user.effects.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Actions, Effect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { map, mergeMap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

import { UserActionTypes, LoadUserAction, LoadUserSuccessAction, LoadUserFailureAction, UpdateUserAction,
    UpdateUserSuccessAction, UpdateUserFailureAction, DeleteUserAction, DeleteUserSuccessAction,
    DeleteUserFailureAction} from '../actions/user.actions';
import { UserService } from 'src/app/core/services/user.service';
import { UserGraphqlService } from 'src/app/core/services/user-graphql.service';
import { User } from 'src/app/shared/models/user.model';

// Effects perform operation base on any action called by components or services
@Injectable()
export class UserEffects {

    constructor(private actions$: Actions,
                private userService: UserService,
                private userGraphqlService: UserGraphqlService) { }

    @Effect()
    loadUser$ = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType<LoadUserAction>(UserActionTypes.LOAD_USER),
        mergeMap(() => this.userService.sendUserQueryRequest(this.userGraphqlService.getUserListGraphqlString()).pipe(
            map((data: User[]) => {
                return new LoadUserSuccessAction(data);
            }),
            catchError(error => of(new LoadUserFailureAction(error)))
        ))
    );
}
```

problem is in load user listing
user.reducers.ts

```
import { createFeatureSelector, createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';
import { User } from 'src/app/shared/models/user.model';
import { UserAction, UserActionTypes } from '../actions/user.actions';
import { EntityState, EntityAdapter, createEntityAdapter } from '@ngrx/entity';

export interface UserState extends EntityState<User> {
    selectedCustomerId: number | null;
    loading: boolean;
    error: Error;
}

export const userAdapter: EntityAdapter<User> = createEntityAdapter<User>();
export const defaultUser: UserState = {
ids: [],
entities: {},
selectedCustomerId: null,
loading: false,
error: undefined
};
// Define intialstate value of app state
export const initialState = userAdapter.getInitialState(defaultUser);

// Change store app state as per actions
export function UserReducer(state: UserState = initialState, action: UserAction) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case UserActionTypes.LOAD_USER:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            };

        case UserActionTypes.LOAD_USER_SUCCESS:
            return userAdapter.addAll(action.payload, {
                ...state,
                // list: action.payload,
                loading: false
            });

        case UserActionTypes.LOAD_USER_FAILURE:
            return {
                ...state,
                entities: {},
                error: action.payload,
                loading: false
            };
        case UserActionTypes.UPDATE_USER:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            };
        case UserActionTypes.UPDATE_USER_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                entities: {},
                loading: false
            };
        case UserActionTypes.UPDATE_USER_FAILURE:
            return {
                ...state,
                error: action.payload,
                loading: false
            };
        case UserActionTypes.DELETE_USER:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            };
        case UserActionTypes.DELETE_USER_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                entities: {},
                // list: {
                //     ...state.list,
                //     Users: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.list)).Users.
                //           filter(item => item.Username !==
                //           JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(action.payload)).Username)
                // },
                loading: false
            };
        case UserActionTypes.DELETE_USER_FAILURE:
            return {
                ...state,
                error: action.payload,
                loading: false
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}


const getUserFeatureState = createFeatureSelector<UserState>('user');

// This selector use to fetch all users
export const getUsers = createSelector(
    getUserFeatureState,
    userAdapter.getSelectors().selectAll,
);

// This selector use to fetch loading value
export const getUsersLoading = createSelector(
    getUserFeatureState,
    (state: UserState) => state.loading
);

// This selector use to fetch error value
export const getError = createSelector(
    getUserFeatureState,
    (state: UserState) => state.error
);

// This selector use to fetch specific users base on id
export const getUser = (id: string ) => createSelector(
    getUserFeatureState,
    userAdapter.getSelectors().selectAll,
    // (state: UserState) => {
    //     const jsonResponse = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.list));
    //     if (jsonResponse && jsonResponse.Users && jsonResponse.Users.length > 0) {
    //         const selectedUser = jsonResponse.Users.filter(user => user.Username === id)[0];
    //         return selectedUser;
    //     } else {
    //         return {};
    //     }
    // }
);
```

user.actions.ts

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { User } from 'src/app/shared/models/user.model';

// Define all possible action types base on action reducer change state
export enum UserActionTypes {
    LOAD_USER = '[User] Load User',
    LOAD_USER_SUCCESS = '[User] Load User Success',
    LOAD_USER_FAILURE = '[User] Load User Failure',

    UPDATE_USER = '[User] Update User',
    UPDATE_USER_SUCCESS = '[User] Update User Success',
    UPDATE_USER_FAILURE = '[User] Update User Failure',

    DELETE_USER = '[User] Delete User',
    DELETE_USER_SUCCESS = '[User] Delete User Success',
    DELETE_USER_FAILURE = '[User] Delete User Failure',

}

// Use when load all the users
export class LoadUserAction implements Action {
    readonly type = UserActionTypes.LOAD_USER;
}

// Use when getting successful all user data
export class LoadUserSuccessAction implements Action {
    readonly type = UserActionTypes.LOAD_USER_SUCCESS;
    constructor(public payload: Array<User>) { }
}

// Use when getting an error while loading user data
export class LoadUserFailureAction implements Action {
    readonly type = UserActionTypes.LOAD_USER_FAILURE;
    constructor(public payload: Error) { }
}
// Update User
export class UpdateUserAction implements Action {
    readonly type = UserActionTypes.UPDATE_USER;
    constructor(public payload: User) { }
}
// Update User Success
export class UpdateUserSuccessAction implements Action {
    readonly type = UserActionTypes.UPDATE_USER_SUCCESS;
    constructor(public payload: User) { }
}

// Update User Failure
export class UpdateUserFailureAction implements Action {
    readonly type = UserActionTypes.UPDATE_USER_FAILURE;
    constructor(public payload: Error) { }
}

// Delete User
export class DeleteUserAction implements Action {
    readonly type = UserActionTypes.DELETE_USER;
    constructor(public payload: User) { }
}
// Delete User Success
export class DeleteUserSuccessAction implements Action {
    readonly type = UserActionTypes.DELETE_USER_SUCCESS;
    constructor(public payload: User) { }
}

// Delete User Failure
export class DeleteUserFailureAction implements Action {
    readonly type = UserActionTypes.DELETE_USER_FAILURE;
    constructor(public payload: Error) { }
}


export type UserAction = LoadUserAction | LoadUserSuccessAction |
                         LoadUserFailureAction | UpdateUserAction | UpdateUserSuccessAction | UpdateUserFailureAction |
                         DeleteUserAction | DeleteUserSuccessAction | DeleteUserFailureAction;
```

user.graphql.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class UserGraphqlService {

    getUserListGraphqlString() {
        return `query {
            listUsers {
              Users {
                  Attributes {
                      Name,
                      Value
                    },
                    UserCreateDate,
                    UserLastModifiedDate,
                    Username,
                    UserStatus,
                    Group,
                    Enabled
                },
              user_pool_id,
              user_name,
              group_name,
              message,
              result
            }
          }`;
    }
}
```

where, user.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { map, mergeMap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
// Use to fetch data from the server
export class UserService {

    private URL = '';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.URL = environment.URL;
    }

    sendUserQueryRequest(data) {
        return this.http.post<any>(this.URL + '/query', data).pipe(map(val => val.data.listUsers));
    }
    deleteUserQueryRequest(data) {
        return this.http.post<any>(this.URL + '/query', data).pipe(map(val => val.data.deleteUser));
    }
}
```

getting an error

```
core.js:6014 ERROR TypeError: entities is not iterable
    at addManyMutably (http://localhost:4200/users-users-module.js:214:30)
    at setAllMutably (http://localhost:4200/users-users-module.js:227:9)
    at Object.operation [as addAll] (http://localhost:4200/users-users-module.js:149:27)
    at UserReducer (http://localhost:4200/users-users-module.js:3033:32)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:267485:20
    at combination (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:267373:37)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:268249:27
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:267453:20
    at computeNextEntry (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:266247:21)
    at recomputeStates (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:266300:15)
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```js
// This selector use to fetch specific users base on id
export const getUser = (id: string ) => createSelector(
    getUserFeatureState,
    userAdapter.getSelectors().selectAll,
    // (state: UserState) => {
    //     const jsonResponse = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.list));
    //     if (jsonResponse && jsonResponse.Users && jsonResponse.Users.length > 0) {
    //         const selectedUser = jsonResponse.Users.filter(user => user.Username === id)[0];
    //         return selectedUser;
    //     } else {
    //         return {};
    //     }
    // }
);
```

to this:

```js
// This selector use to fetch specific users base on id
export const getUser = (id: string ) => createSelector(
    getUsers,
    (users) => users.find( user => user.id === id)
);
```

And use the entity adapter to set the state. ex.

```js
case ABC:
 return userEntityAdapter.addMany({...state, loading: false}, action.payload.users);
```

You can find some examples [here](https://ngrx.io/guide/entity/adapter).